Error in cv2.rectangle after flipping image with slicing: 'Layout of the output array img is incompatible with cv::Mat'
I am using OpenCV to draw a rectangle on a binary image. My goal is to draw the rectangle on both the original image and its vertically flipped version. However, I encounter an issue when flipping the image using the slicing method. Here’s the code snippet I am using:
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Create a binary image
binary_image = np.zeros((100, 100), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.rectangle(binary_image, (10, 10), (30, 30), (255), -1)

# Flip the image using slicing
flipped_slicing = binary_image[::-1]
# Try to draw a rectangle on the flipped image
cv2.rectangle(flipped_slicing, (10, 10), (30, 30), (255), -1)

# Flip the image using cv2.flip
flipped_cv2 = cv2.flip(binary_image, 0)
# Draw a rectangle on the flipped image
cv2.rectangle(flipped_cv2, (10, 10), (30, 30), (255), -1)

The issue is that cv2.rectangle works perfectly on the image flipped with cv2.flip, but it fails when using the slicing method [::-1]. I expected both methods to produce similar results. Can anyone explain why this difference occurs and how to resolve it?
flipped_slicing_method = binary_image[::-1]
flipped_cv = cv2.flip(binary_image, 0)
print(np.all(flipped_slicing_method==flipped_cv))

>> True

But when I run this code, I get an error.
cv2.rectangle(flipped_slicing_method, (0,0), (400, 400), 255,-1)

the Error is:
error: OpenCV(4.9.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'rectangle'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Layout of the output array img is incompatible with cv::Mat
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'
>  - Layout of the output array img is incompatible with cv::Mat
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'


A look at the flags attribute of the Numpy arrays, shows that slicing gives non contiguous data, and that the result does not own this data:
>>> flipped_slicing.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False

>>> flipped_cv2.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False

This is confirmed by the strides attributes:
>>> flipped_slicing.strides
(-100, 1)

>>> flipped_cv2.strides
(100, 1)

OpenCV can operate on non-contiguous arrays, but it requires the stride (called "step" in the documentation) to be non negative. So your code will work with positive slicing, but not with negative one, as you need for your flipping operation.

IDK if opencv matrices have finally gotten more flexible in terms of striding. it used to be (still is?) that the channel values of a pixel must be packed... and I think even the pixels must be packed, so no space between pixels. there might have been a flavor of Mat with fully custom dimensions, but IDK if that would be easily usable in most of the APIs. I usually just use OpenCV in Python, and if a numpy array ever doesn't match a Mat, ascontiguousarray or a copy is good enough to cure the problem.

@ChristophRackwitz At least in 4.x the channel values need to be packed, since on the C++ side they're treated as a plain old array of relevant datatype (wrapped in a struct Vec -> Matx). And strides (MatStep) are still size_t, which is unsigned. (Seems like in 5.x it's still like that.) | I think I did see 4.10 recently accept something from Python that I thought it shouldn't have, but didn't dig deeper... may be that the wrappers now do a copy when it's input only, but that's just a wild speculation.

@ChristophRackwitz And yeah, pixels must be packed too. Normal Mats are 2D and number of strides must be ndims-1, so just positive row stride. | I suppose it's a useful prerequisite for vectorized implementations of many of the algorithms.

When flipping the matrix, the python script does not make sure that it is stored as a solid chunk. OpenCV usually operates on contiguous arrays, hence you need to do this:
flipped_slicing = np.ascontiguousarray(binary_image[::-1])

This should solve the problem.

See edit history and comments for previous wrong statement that I did

the only relevant part of the assertion is Layout of the output array img is incompatible with cv::Mat, which says that numpy arrays are more flexible than cv::Mat. -- I wouldn't put much stock in the exact wording of the overload resolution failed assertion. especially not when a UMat is mentioned. that's implementation detail. "ptr of" is not an obtainable distinction in python for sure, and in C++ it shouldn't be (cv::Mat is a kind of smart pointer).

"it expectes a pointer to the matrix (Ptrcv::UMat)" -- no, UMat usage here was not intended (they would be constructed explicitly). It's just an implementation detail of the Python wrapper's overload handling, part of which is support for both Mat and UMat (Which on C++ side is handled by InputArray et al). Since there isn't an explicit Mat in Python, the wrapper first tries to convert whatever it is given to a Mat and if that fails, it tries to make it a UMat (and repeats for other C++ overloads). When all fail, you get an error listing all attempts.
